# Getting a variable value from inside an object in an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to assign a variable to a value that is held inside an object in an Observable in my typescript file. I am able to return the variable as a value in my HTML file, so I know I'm probably missing something really obvious and I think the solution is to do with two-way binding but I just have not been able to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppState } from '../store';
import { State, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import * as fromCurrencies from '../store/actions/currencies.actions';
import { Currency } from '../Models/currency';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as fromSelectors from '../store/selectors/currencies.selectors';
import { selectCurrency } from '../store/selectors/currencies.selectors';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}
  public currency$: Observable<Currency>;
  public conversionRate: number;
  public convertedAmount: number;
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  OnSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log('currency: ' + form.value.symbol);
    this.store.dispatch(
      fromCurrencies.findCurrency({
        symbol: form.value.symbol,
      })
    );
    this.currency$ = this.store.select(fromSelectors.selectCurrency);
    this.convertedAmount = form.value.amount * this.conversionRate;
  }
}
```

The interface:

```
  id: number;
  symbol: string;
  name: string;
  conversionRate: number;
}
```

I want to assign value of the conversionRate inside Currency to the variable conversionRate inside the typescript file. I'll also add the realted HTML, where I know how to get the value.

```
<div>
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(form)">
    <div class="currency-type">
      <label for="symbol">Symbol</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="symbol"
        ngModel
        required
        id="symbol"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="enter symbol"
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="amount">Amount (€): </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="amount"
        ngModel
        required
        id="amount"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="enter amount"
      />
    </div>
    <button
      type="submit"
      [disabled]="form.invalid"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
    >
      <span>Calculate Currency</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>

<table *ngIf="currency$ | async as currencyInfo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Symbol</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Conversion Rate</th>
      <th>Amount (Euro)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr *ngFor="let curr of currencyInfo">
    <td>{{ curr.symbol }}</td>
    <td>{{ curr.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ curr.conversionRate }}</td> //value I want to assign in ts file
    <td>{{ conversionRate }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Edit: I have successfully fixed this issue by using the for loop inside the table in the form as well, and I can then define a select tag equal to the value. The new HTML code is shown below:

```
<div *ngIf="currency$ | async as currencyInfo">
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(form)">
    <div class="currency-type">
      <label for="symbol">Symbol</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="symbol"
        ngModel
        required
        id="symbol"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="enter symbol"
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="amount">Amount (€): </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="amount"
        ngModel
        required
        id="amount"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="enter amount"
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Conversion Rate:</label>
      <select
        *ngFor="let curr of currencyInfo"
        name="rate"
        type="number"
        id="rate"
        ngModel
        class="form-control"
        value="{{ curr.conversionRate }}"
        id="rate"
      >
        <option>
          {{ curr.conversionRate }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button
      type="submit"
      [disabled]="form.invalid"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
    >
      <span>Calculate Currency</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>

<table *ngIf="currency$ | async as currencyInfo">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Converted Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of currencyInfo">
    <td>{{ convertedAmount }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, that's not exactly what I'm trying to do. I don't want the value of ```curr.conversionRate``` to change, I'm just trying to access it via the ts file instead of the html file

Answer (score 0):

If you want update your `curr.conversionRate` then you can use an `input` and bind using `[(ngModel)]` like below=>

**HTML:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of currencyInfo">
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <tr>
            <input type="number" (ngModelChange)="dataChanged(data,$event)" [(ngModel)]="data.conversionRate">
        </tr>
    </td>
    <td>{{data.conversionRate }}</td>
</tr>
```

**TS:**

```
dataChanged(data,$event){
   //console.log(data);
   //console.log($event);
  }
```

**Note:** Here is a demo link you can check => [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-rowspan-xtdkdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).